# When to use colon in a Vue emit name?

Tags: vue.js, events, eventemitter

So, I'm trying to understand code written by someone else and there's one thing I haven't figured out. Why would you use colon in an emit-name?
Here's an example:

```
this.$emit('update:compare', { key, values })
```

The problem is that I can't find the component listening to this emit. I've been looking for `v-on:update:compare=""` and `@update:compare=""` but I can't find it. What does the colon even do?

I've found this other thing in the same component as the emit that I don't recognise either:

```
  model: {
    prop: 'compare',
    event: 'update:compare',
  },
```

And I guess it has something to do with it but I can't figure it out. 
Would anyone be so kind to shed some light on this for me, please?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: Thanks, that explains some of it. So, colon is just a way to document what we intend to do. 

But I guess you have to have a handler on the parent that  matches that, like `<component @update:compare="callback">` which I don’t have.

Comment: Yes. There must be a handler in the parent component that handles the event emitted

Comment: @Magistern, it's not `@update:compare`. It's `:compare.sync`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be specific re. documentation in link in comments above (which is worth reading), you can add .sync to a v-bind in order to allow props to be passed back "up" to the parent automatically (2 way binding). I wasn't aware of this either until I started delving into the vue query builder library and had exactly the same problem as OP. https://github.com/dabernathy89/vue-query-builder

```
<some-component :someData.sync="someData" />


// Inside component method:
this.$emit('update:someData', "New value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this documentation in vuejs docs.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

WAY-1
For this to actually work though, the  component must do two things:
Bind the value attribute of a native  element to the modelValue prop
When a native input event is triggered, emit an update:modelValue custom event with the new value

```
 <!-- CustomInput.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>

<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>
```

WAY-2

Another way of implementing v-model within this component is to use a writable computed property with both a getter and a setter. The get method should return the modelValue property and the set method should emit the corresponding event:

```
    <!-- CustomInput.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="value" />
</template>
```